# 04091. 00000 - "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

What am I supposed to do here? I am trying to count the pid in lagerbewegung to find out how many different products are in one silo.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Check_produkt_in_silo
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON silo
FOR EACH ROW

declare
anzProdukt number;

BEGIN
  select distinct COUNT(pid) into anzProdukt from lagerbewegung where silonr = :old.silonr;
  
  if anzProdukt > 1 then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(-20398, 'In Silo ' || :new.silonr || ' wurde ein 2. Produkt eingefügt');
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: That's not *that* trigger; it is based on SILO table, while it selects values from LAGERBEWEGUNG.

Comment: The trigger you've shown is invalid anyway; it should be calling `raise_application_error()` not `dbms_output.put_line()` - which only takes one argument. So perhaps the trigger that's actually defined in the database is different to the source code you're looking at? And I suspect you meant `count(distinct pid)` rather than `distinct count(pid)`.